# How to implement the server URL in a python program

Tags: python, web, request, response

I'm new to python. And I extracted some links from twitter and tried to use the Memento Aggregator to create a histogram. I've already used docker online playground to open the Memento Aggregator and how do I write a program to implement these links from a txt to the Memento Aggregator?

My current code is

```
import requests

host = 'https://www.katacoda.com/courses/docker/playground'
with open('Extracted links.txt', 'w') as f:
    for line in f:
    response = requests.get(host+"/timemap/json/"+line)
```

I used tweepy to extract some links. Here are some samples.
https://www.mytownneo.com/sports/20200215/no-comeback-this-time-barberton-crushes-tallmadge-boys-basketball
https://twitter.com/i/web/status/1228709479589404672
https://www.sctimes.com/story/sports/2020/02/14/albany-beats-no-1-sauk-centre-final-seconds/4768857002/
http://www.fiba.basketball/fiba-once-again-top-in-international-sports-federations-social-media-ranking-report-for-2019
https://twitter.com/i/web/status/1228709487600640000
How to write a python program to implement them in the docker containment and use the memogator to process these links?
I use this playground to run memogator.（https://www.katacoda.com/courses/docker/playground） I tried to let Memogator timemap to process these links but I got stuck at implementing these url links to the MemoGator.This is MemoGator which can process links. And here is the GitHub link. github.com/oduwsdl/memgator [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTT9J.png)

Comment: Add some sample lines from `Extracted links.txt`. From your current code, you will be getting an intendetation error since `response = ` is not intended one block right. It's also worth noting that once you have the `response` object, you need to do something to it to have any effect -- a simple `print(response.status_code)` should be enough to give you an idea if you've reached the page successfully ([ref.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) for what numbers to look out for).

Comment: I used tweepy to extract some links. Here are some samples.
https://www.mytownneo.com/sports/20200215/no-comeback-this-time-barberton-crushes-tallmadge-boys-basketball
https://twitter.com/i/web/status/1228709479589404672
https://www.sctimes.com/story/sports/2020/02/14/albany-beats-no-1-sauk-centre-final-seconds/4768857002/
http://www.fiba.basketball/fiba-once-again-top-in-international-sports-federations-social-media-ranking-report-for-2019
https://twitter.com/i/web/status/1228709487600640000

Comment: How to write a python program to implement them in the docker containment and use the memogator to process these links?

Comment: https://www.katacoda.com/courses/docker/playground
I use this playground to run memogator.
I tried to let Memogator timemap to process these links but I got stuck at implementing these links to the MemoGator.

Comment: enter image description here
This is MemoGator which can process links. And here is the GitHub link. https://github.com/oduwsdl/memgator

Comment: Edit your post and add details -- no bueno doing so via comments.

Answer (score -1):

You can use wget package to download the file and read the file:

```
import wget

url="your URL"
filename = wget.download(url)
#Read csv/text
pdf = pd.read_csv(filename)
print ("Shape of dataset: ", pdf.shape)
print(pdf.head(5))
```